# WPF ListView-GridView : bind image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listview, gridview

I'm working on a desktop WPF app (.net 4). One of its window contains a `tabControl` whose `tabitems` contain each a`Listview`, whose view is a `GridView`. TabItems, ListViews and GridViews are all dynamically generated. When the user hits a button on each tabitem, the ListView view is updated with a DataTable defaultview from `SQL Server` (of course, the selected rows depend on user's request, but that's irrelevant here).

Everything is working just fine, with the (shortened) code below for the `GridView` (gv) generated dynamically :

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> Column in Columns)
{
    GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
    gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(Column.Key);
    gv.Columns.Add(gvc);
}
```

As you can see, I created a Dictionary with column names matching the columns of the DataTable received from SQL Server (I use the Column.Value for special use, also irrelevant here).

My question is "simple" :

One of the column contains a value which I would like to show as a logo ; plainly, the SQL server column contains strings (let's say, "a" or "b") and I have images named "a.png" and "b.png" (which I can display dynamically, like `testimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../images/a.png", UriKind.Relative))`).

So, how could I, in c#, replace the "a" and "b" letters in my ListView column by "a.png" and "b.png" ?

I hope I'm clear and already thank every people who will take on their time to read and try to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Data Binding ValueConverter for this

Your converter class -

```
    public class MyImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string imageName = (string) value;
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../images/" + imageName + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

In your code-behind

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> Column in Columns)
{
    GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
    Binding binding = new Binding(Column.Key);
    if (Column.Key == "Image")
    {
        binding.Converter = new MyImageConverter();
    }
    gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = binding;
    gv.Columns.Add(gvc);
}
```

Comment: Thx, but it doesn't work : the displaymemberbinding just shows the path sent by MyImageConverter ; however, the all-code solution is the way to go, but my problem is to create in code-behind a datatemplate which points to the converter...

Comment: Ok, I got it, see the full answer on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0de6df72-856a-4dc4-a063-ffc32baa393d